# What are the advantages of separating FK and deform bones in an IK/FK rig?

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints, drivers

In an IK/FK rig is there any advantage to having a set of deform bones (DEF bones) that are separate from the FK bones? This is opposed to a setup where you have one set of bones you make FK adjustments to that also deforms the mesh and can switched to IK using drivers.

[image: FK/IK/DEF vs FK/IK as DEF]

Example blend attached.

[image]

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118919/what-is-the-standard-3-rig-setup), but my other question is more about context and conventions.

Answer (score 1):

One advantage is that you can see the FK bones actual positions without adjusting the IK/FK switch. This might be useful when blending halfway between IK and FK in order to transition from one to the other. When going from IK to FK you can set your FK positions to their destination position and then adjust the switch and see the deform transition state. You'll still be able to adjust the destination FK position while seeing the resulting transition state without having to go back and forth between them.

Comment: It may also have to do with avoiding cyclic dependencies in Blender's dependency graph. I can't find concrete examples of where this is or was a problem.